# Always have an footer bar at end of screen?

Tags: android, footer

I have to always show some buttons at the end of the screen. My application has multiple activities so I want it to be easy to implement in all of them. I know that I can include a footer within xml. But the problem is that I don't want the footer to overlay the other content. I want to be able to use something like this:

```
<include layout="@layout/footer" />
```

Then the code would "make room" for a footer. So if I for example have listview, the listview won't be under the footer instead the listviews render-area will end where the footer begins.

As I mentioned before, the footer has buttons which in turn has to fire a function regardless of which activity it's currently in. Also if it's possible in some way I would want to use:

```
imageButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path);
imageButton.setBackground(new BitmapDrawable(bm));
```

for each of the buttons.

So to summarise it. Is there any way of always showing a layout firing functions at the end of the screen?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I recommend that you don't do this.  Apps with buttons at the bottom are a pain in Android since this is where the home, back and menu buttons are.  Don't copy iOS.  Do it the Android way.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you split your views with Layouts? Something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="510dp"></LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"></LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Other than that, I remember reading once that you can force the ActionBar to be at the bottom. Maybe you can use that?